# How to split a DockablePane into CView and CFormView

Tags: mfc

I'm wondering how we can use CSplitterWndEx to split a DockablePane into CView (used to draw Rectangles/Lines etc..) and CFormView (used to place UI controls such as buttons, comboBox, and the likes ..). The DockablePane will be part of an MDI application. A code sample would be very helpful. I tried the below code on MyDockablePane::OnCreate function but it simply shows an "blank" DockablePane window without a splitter: (Thanks for your time looking into it)

```
int MyDockablePane::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs)
{
   if (CDockablePane::OnCreate(lpcs) == -1)
     return -1;

  CRect cr;
  GetClientRect(&cr);

  m_wndSplitter.CreateStatic(this,1,2);

  // MyFormView derived from CFormView
  if (!m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(MyFormView),
    CSize(cr.Width() *48/100, cr.Height()), NULL))
  {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // MyCView derived from CView
  if (!m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 1, RUNTIME_CLASS(MyCView),
    CSize(cr.Width() * 52/100, cr.Height()), NULL))
  {
    return FALSE;
  }

  return TRUE;
```

}

// On the MainFrame I'm calling DockablePane's Create, ShowPane, 
// EnableDocking, and MainFrame's DockPane

Comment: can't you create two dockable panes? one with the CView and one with the CFormView? you can add pointers to eachother so they can easily communicate.

Comment: Thanks Robson for the idea.I can create CPaneDialog if I need a DockablePane with a CFormView. The issue I'm facing is I want both of them (CView and CFormView) on the same Window. I come from C++ Borland Builder background and do not realize MFC is this tough.

Comment: welcome onboard then! =)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add at the end of your code:

```
m_wndSplitter.SetWindowPos(NULL,cr.left, cr.top, cr.Width(), cr.Height(), SWP_NOZORDER);
m_wndSplitter.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: before the  'return TRUE;' =)